# Q: How to clear cells after archiving?

Tags: excel, archiving, vba

I have put together a Macro that allows me to archive Data from one sheet to another however I am having trouble having it Clear the info afterwards. The first Column contains numbers that I do not want to clear, right now it is only clearing the data in column B.

If someone could take a look at this I would be very greatful.

```
'Sub archive()
Dim i, lastrow
Dim mytext As String
lastrow = Sheets("Rooms").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
mytext = Sheets("Rooms").Cells(i, "F").Text
If InStr(mytext, "yes") Then
Sheets("Rooms").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Sheets("Rooms").Cells(i, "B").Clear
End If
Next i
End Sub'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the cell on the associated row in column B and extended it to the last cell on the same row containing any value.

```
Sub archive()
    Dim i, lastrow
    Dim mytext As String

    With WorkSheets("Rooms")
        lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            mytext = .Cells(i, "F").Text
            If InStr(1, mytext, "yes", vbTextCompare) Then
                .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Clear
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Additionally, I've used a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to associate `WorkSheets("Rooms")` with all of its cells to avoid repetitive worksheet referencing.

The [Range.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223824%28v=office.11%29.aspx) command scrubs all values and formatting. If you just want the values to be removed, you may want to switch to [Range.ClearContents method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223828%28v=office.11%29.aspx).